# Get All possible number of combinations

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I need to access all possible number of combinations of characters in a string. Without Using Any loop, because i have to filter records in thousands. loop can give performance issue. 
lets Take a Example :
 **Any Custom method**
ABCD ===>>
ABCD, ABDC,ACBD,ACDB, ADCB, BACD, BADC, BCAD, BCDA, BDAC , BDCA , CADB,CBDA,CDBA, CBAD, DABC, DBCA, DCBA,DCAB......

thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you tried someone ? If so can you show us ? Or this is a case of "Do it for me please" ?

Comment: A bit underspecified. Can the string characters repeat, or are they all unique?

Comment: Yes Dear Only unique, nothing should be missed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service!

Comment: `C`!=`C++`!=`Objective C` Please decide for one language only.

Comment: dear All , i just want logic, language does not matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in fact a function in the C++ standard library for this: [std::next_permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation). Here is the example from the link, adapted to your case.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "ABCD";
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    do
    {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
    }
    while(std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
}
```

Online [here](http://ideone.com/n5Yb9B)

Comment: dear please give custom logic for next_permutation... no need of inbuilt function

Comment: Just look at the **Possible implementation** here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation